# Fetching data from firebase to SwiftUI

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

Im learning SwiftUI and doing a simple application with firebase.
My problem is fetching data (in real time)

Here is how the app works.
I have Loan objects and payment objects.

in the 1st view (list) i fetch all my loans in real time, can add/delete and it works.
When i click on any loan object, it will take me to 2nd view (payments) where i have all the payments inserted for that loan. in order to download my payments, i need to provide my loanId so firebase will filter my payments and send me only the payments for selected loan. the problem is when i pass my loanId to my payments view in transition i dont know to do do this because my model that downloads my payments is being called before I do the transfer of the loanId.

Any advise would be much appreciated.

Here is my code in LoansView
struct LoansView: View {

```
 @State private var showingAddLoan = false
    @ObservedObject var dataListener = LoanListener()

    var body: some View {

        NavigationView {
            List(dataListener.loans) { loan in

                NavigationLink(destination: LoanDetailView(loan: loan)) {
                    ListCell(loan: loan)
                }

            }
            .navigationBarTitle("All Loans")
            .navigationBarItems(trailing:

                Button(action: {
                    self.showingAddLoan.toggle()
                }) {
                    Image(systemName: "plus")
            })
                .sheet(isPresented: self.$showingAddLoan) {
                    AddLoanView()
            }

        }

    }
}
```

my loanListener

```
import Foundation
import Firebase

class LoanListener: ObservableObject {

    @Published var loans = [Loan]()

    init() {
        downloadLoans()
    }

    func downloadLoans() {

        FirebaseReference(.User).document("1234").collection(kLOAN_PATH).addSnapshotListener { (snapshot, error) in

            guard let snapshot = snapshot else {  return }

            if !snapshot.isEmpty {

                self.loans = LoanListener.loanFromDictionaries(snapshot)

            }

        }
    }

    static func loanFromDictionaries(_ snapshot: QuerySnapshot) -> [Loan] {

        var allLoans: [Loan] = []


        for loanData in snapshot.documents {

            allLoans.append(Loan(loanData.data() as NSDictionary))
        }

        return allLoans
    }

}
```

this is my payment listener, but the issue is i have to provide loanId to it to get correct payments

```
import Foundation
import Firebase

class PaymentListener: ObservableObject {

    @Published var payments = [Payment]()

    init(forLoan: Loan) {
        downloadPayments(forLoan)
    }

    func downloadPayments(_ forLoan: Loan) {

        FirebaseReference(.User).document("1234").collection(kPAYMENT_PATH).whereField(kLOANID, isEqualTo: forLoan.id).addSnapshotListener { (snapshot, error) in

            guard let snapshot = snapshot else {  return }
            print("too")
            if !snapshot.isEmpty {
                print("have")
                self.payments = PaymentListener.paymentFromDictionaries(snapshot)
                print(self.payments.count)
            }

        }
    }

    static func paymentFromDictionaries(_ snapshot: QuerySnapshot) -> [Payment] {

        var allPayments: [Payment] = []


        for paymentData in snapshot.documents {

            allPayments.append(Payment(paymentData.data() as NSDictionary))
        }

        return allPayments
    }

}
```

and this is my payments view where i want to show payments of each loan

```
struct LoanDetailView: View {

    @State var showingAddPayment = false

    var loan: Loan
    @ObservedObject var allPayments = PaymentListener(forLoan: loan)

    var body: some View {

        List(allPayments) { payment in
            PaymentCell(payment: payment)
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("loan.name", displayMode: .inline)
        .navigationBarItems(trailing:

            Button(action: {
                self.showingAddPayment.toggle()
            }) {
                Image(systemName: "plus")
        })
            .sheet(isPresented: self.$showingAddPayment) {
                AddPaymentView(loanId: self.loan.id)
        }

    }
}
```

but im getting this 
[image: error]

Comment: can you show me how you're fetching and managing the data from firebase and the way you're passing the loanId

Comment: Try making the `loan` in `LoanDetailsView` a `@Published` property. Also, remove `forLoan` from `PaymentListener`'s initialiser, and make it a property on `PaymentListener`. Finally, in `LoanDetailView`'s initialiser, set up a Combine pipeline that subscribes to the `loan` publisher, and updates the `loan` property on `PaymentListener` whenever it changes.